# How to verify two child nodes belong to the same parent by Appium

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

My first question in StackOverflow!

I met a problem in app automation that, I need to find an element from a list by a specific text name and then get another text from that same element, how should I achieve that?

```
level1: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
level2: android.widget.LinearLayout
level3: android.widget.LinearLayout
level4: android.widget.TextView: ABC + android.widget.TextView: XYZ
```

I need to get ‘XYZ’ by searching 'ABC'.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please share image of locators with appium inspector ?

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to add unique ID to both TextView elements.

If you can't do that you could use xpath. [Really good cheat-sheet.](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf)

In your case it would be:

`By.xpath(.//android.widget.TextView[@text='ABC']/following-sibling::android.widget.TextView)`